# Words go beyond the line when acronym first used

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment, acronyms

The alignment of words is not maintained in justified alignment when an acronym is first used. It only happens when it is a first used acronym. I have attempted the ''microtype''-package, but did not help. Do you have any advice or recommendations on how to address this matter?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: tex can not hyphenate such a string by default, not will it be able to stretch white space you have nit shown enough to wrap that to the next line while justifying the paragraph. what do you want it to do? try `\sloppy` before the text but provide a real example

Comment: Thanks, I just put `\sloppy` before text begin, it solved the problem!